# How to attach data to TreeItem in SWT/Java?

Tags: java, tree, swt

I'm starting to use the SWT GUI toolkit in Java. I have a need to attach some data to the TreeItems. Each toolkit I've previously used had a tree item, which contained a raw pointer or a base object reference to provide basic data containment, but I cannot find one in TreeItem in SWT.

How can I attach data to the TreeItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: with pure SWT you cant't.
The *Standard Widget Toolkit* only takes care of the widgets, their hierarchy and the visual representation. Binding data to widgets is topic of the more advanced JFace framework (especially it's databinding facilities) which builds on top of SWT. You need some time to master it, but therefore you gain the power of the Eclipse platform. It enables you to bind a model to view, even in both direction
(→ change to model object are immediately reflected on the UI and vice versa).
Currently, you would have to keep a seperate list of items and need to work with indices.

Comment: I see. I wish to write really simple application and I don't really want to think about models and connecting presentation to logic. Is there a simpler GUI toolkit, which allows such operations? Or can I - for example - derive from TreeItem and add required fields? Is there a really simple solution to my problem?

Comment: Working with indices is the simplest way. [The documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FTreeItem.html) explicitly states it's not allowed to derive from `TreeItem`. I know Swing only on the very surface, but [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) section from the Java Tutorial seems to be a good resource for working with trees in Swing.

Comment: I feel like I either have to use a single wrench to fix a nuclear power plant or use a Javelin missle launcher to kill a mosquito :( Thanks for your help, anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

This is simple.

```
TreeItem treeItem = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);

treeItem.setData("key", obj);
```

when getting data :

```
Object obj = treeItem.getData("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

In SWT 4.2, and possibly in earlier versions (though I didn't check), the class `TreeItem` is a subclass of `Widget`, and `Widget` has `setData(Object o)` and `getData()`. You can use that to attach arbitrary, application-specific data to `TreeItem` instances.